# Establecer como variable cada linea del output de un comando que sean utilizadas por otro comando dentro de un bash script

Tags: bash, variables, kubernetes, gcp, gcloud

Necesito la informacion de kubernetes para reportes y monitoreo de clusters que se encuentran en GCP, tengo instalada la cli de gcloud y accedo como owner con mi cuenta, tengo un monton de proyectos con de 5 a 10 cluster cada uno por lo que me he construido scripts para automatizar ciertas tareas, en este caso estoy un poco atorado porque para interactuar a nombre del kubeconfig de cada cluster es necesario ejecutar un comando que requiere valores de otro comando.

#Este es el comando que me manda la informacion que necesito:

***gcloud container clusters list***

Me muestra la sigueinte informacion:

```
NAME                 LOCATION            MASTER_VERSION    MASTER_IP       MACHINE_TYPE   NODE_VERSION        NUM_NODES  STATUS
gke-cluster-dsfc-ha  southamerica-east1  1.23.14-gke.1800  35.247.219.142  e2-highmem-8   1.23.14-gke.1800    6          RUNNING
autopilot-poc-1      us-central1         1.23.14-gke.1800  104.197.240.78  e2-medium      1.22.15-gke.1000 *  6          RUNNING
dsfc-finanzas-prod   us-west2            1.24.9-gke.2000   34.102.103.232  e2-standard-4  1.24.9-gke.2000     3          RUNNING
gke-cluster-devops   us-west2            1.23.14-gke.1800  35.236.97.113   e2-standard-4  1.23.14-gke.1800    5          RUNNING
gke-cluster-dsfc     us-west2            1.23.14-gke.1800  34.94.24.177    e2-highmem-8   1.23.14-gke.1800    26         RUNNING
```

Dentro de mi script ya tengo establecida la variante del nombre del cluster $n por lo que el problema es solo para el nombre del cluster y la region por lo que filtre el comando de la siguiente manera:

***gcloud container clusters list|grep -v NAME|awk '{print $1}'|column -t***
#consigue el nombre de los cluster:

```
gke-cluster-dsfc-ha
autopilot-poc-1
dsfc-finanzas-prod
gke-cluster-devops
gke-cluster-dsfc
```

***gcloud container clusters list|grep -v NAME|awk '{print $1}'|column -t***
#consigue el nombre de las regiones:

```
southamerica-east1
us-central1
us-west2
us-west2
us-west2
```

Y busco establecer cada linea del output como una variante ***linea1=$1 linea2=$2 linea3=$3***
y asi hasta la ultima linea en la lista ya que esos datos deben ser insertados en el sigueinte comando en ejecusion

**gcloud container clusters get-credentials *NOMBREDELCLUSTER($a)* --region *REGIONDELCLUSTER($1)* --project *NOMBREDELPROYECTO($n)***

Si consigo esto cualquier consulta se haria en nombre del kubeconfig del cluster del proyecto por lo que kubectl get nodes -o wide imprimiraia en pantalla la informacion que requiero como version de kubernetes, container runtime etc etc para poderla llevar a un archivo xls que me habra en execl para un inventario general.

Aca muestro el script y su progreso:

```
#!/bin/bash
for n in $(gcloud projects list|grep -v 'sys-\|PROJECT_ID\|gam-'|awk '{print $NF}'
#lista los projects de gcp con filtros de cosas que no ocupo y establesco la variable $n para el nombre del proyecto que sera solicitada mas adelante
do
  gcloud config set project $n
#por cada linea del output anterior setea el proyecto para que toda consulta sea al proyecto especifico 
  gcloud config get-value project
#imprime en pantalla el valor del proyecto (mi-proyecto) porque si no lo veo me confundo ademas de usarse como separador en el archivo excel
  gcloud container clusters list|grep -v NAME| awk '{print $1}'
#este comando lista los cluster del proyecto seleccionado y aqui viene el problema, con esos valores del output devo llenar el siguiente comando tal vez tenga que hacerlo 2 veces ya que me faltan 2 valores que es nombre del cluster y la region ya que el valor de --project la establesco al principio del script ($n) que es el nombre del proyecto donde estoy parado
 gcloud container clusters get-credentials ($a) --region ($1) --project dsfc-produccion($n)
 #una vez hecho el comado anterior ya podriamos ejecutar comandos como ... 
 kubectl get nodes -o wide
done
```

Muchas grcias por su apoyo permanezco pendiente saludos :)

Answer (score 0):

Si entiendo bien, en esencia quieres pasar una lista de cadenas separadas por un retorno de línea en una lista en una misma línea. Aquí hay un ejemplo de cómo hacerlo:

```
salida='a1                                      
a2
a3
a4'


IFS=$'\n' lista=( $salida )
variables=''
i=0
for elemento in ${lista[@]}
do
    (( i++ ))
    variables="$variables linea$i='$elemento'"
done
echo "$variables"
```

`salida` tiene cuatro líneas y el resultado del comando es

```
linea1='a1' linea2='a2' linea3='a3' linea4='a4'
```

de manera que sólo tendrías que guardar la salida de tu comando en una variable y aplicar este código.

Quizá la parte más importante del código es la expresión `IFS=$'\n' lista=( $salida )`. Esta crea una lista a partir de los elementos de salida, tomando como separador el caracter de retorno de línea `\n` (`IFS` es *internal field separator*, lo que bash tomará como punto de separación entre varias cadenas). Lo que sigue del código es simplemente concatenar apropiadamente los elementos de la lista en un bucle.

Comment: Hola agradezco mucho tu respuesta pero por desgracia no es en escencia lo que busco hacer es establecer una variante para cada linea de manera separa para que el comando siguiente pueda ser ejecutado segun las variantes previamente seteadas


~]#comando con filtro que lista objetos
output1
output2
output3


gcloud container clusters get-credentials (variante de la primera linea) --region (variante de la segunda linea) --project (variante de la tercera linea)

Comment: No comprendo la pregunta ni la aclaración. Quizá si escribes un ejemplo mínimo de lo que esperas podamos comprender mejor. Puedes incluso editar tu pregunta original para tener espacio suficiente para ello.